# How to figure out query time

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-execution-plan

I have this very long `SQL command` with a lot of `JOIN` and `UNION` statements.

I opened up `Explain Plan Window`, but I can't tell what `Cost`, `Cardinality`, or `Bytes` mean.

Can someone please explain those terms? And does lower necessarily mean faster `query` time?

Answer (score 1):

**Cost** is an *estimation* done by the cost-based query optimizer to choose an adequate execution plan; *usually*, a lower cost is associated with a faster query time, but not always.

**Cardinality** is the *expected* number of rows returned by your query, based on database statistics. Again, it's just an estimation.

**Bytes** is the number of bytes the database expects to read while executing the query.

### References:

- [Using EXPLAIN PLAN](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96533/ex_plan.htm);
- [Cardinality](http://www.oratechinfo.co.uk/cardinality.html).

Answer (score 1):

as I can see in the [oracle Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96533/ex_plan.htm)

> *CARDINALITY:* Estimate by the cost-based approach of the number of rows
>   accessed by the operation.
>
> *BYTES:* Estimate by the cost-based approach of the number of bytes
>   accessed by the operation.
>
> *COST:* Cost of the operation as estimated by the optimizer's cost-based
>   approach. For statements that use the rule-based approach, this column
>   is null. Cost is not determined for table access operations. The value
>   of this column does not have any particular unit of measurement; it is
>   merely a weighted value used to compare costs of execution plans. The
>   value of this column is a function of the CPU_COST and IO_COST
>   columns.

So, you also need to know:

> *CPU_COST:*  CPU cost of the operation as estimated by the optimizer's cost-based approach. For statements that use the rule-based approach,
>   this column is null. The value of this column is proportional to the
>   number of machine cycles required for the operation.
>
> *IO_COST:* I/O cost of the operation as estimated by the optimizer's cost-based approach. For statements that use the rule-based approach,
>   this column is null. The value of this column is proportional to the
>   number of data blocks read by the operation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know that Explain Plan gives you the plan that the database thinks it will use, but the actual plan that is used can be different.

If you are going to optimize the query, or benchmark it against other queries (to chose the best one), measuring execution time, waits, size of redo and logical i/o are the good places to start. I would not rely on Explain Plan too much.

Have a look at:

http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL_Trace

and:

http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/TKProf